# Translating default "already exists" message

Tags: django

When adding `unique_together` constraints, the form's `clean()` method will perform a check on uniqueness, and if not unique, will throw an error message like:

> (Object) with this (Field1), (Field2) et (Field4) already exists.

I'm not using translation through .mo/.po files in my Django project; all my custom validation messages are translated in my language anyway.

**What is the proper way to set the translation for this (once, project wide)?** Preferably without going the .PO file translation route.

Note: the funny thing is that the word `and` in the above error quote *is* translated to my language (`et`).

Using Django 1.7.7.

Answer (score 1):

This was added in [Django 1.7](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/forms/modelforms/):

> You can override the error messages from NON_FIELD_ERRORS raised by model validation by adding the NON_FIELD_ERRORS key to the error_messages dictionary of the ModelForm’s inner Meta class

The following Meta class can be added to `DefaultForm` (which is then used as a parent for all other forms):

```
class Meta:
    error_messages = {
        NON_FIELD_ERRORS: {
            'unique_together': "%(model_name)s's %(field_labels)s are not unique.",
        }
    }
```